Frontdoor gives a 404, but the hitting app service directly works
I have an Azure Front Door setup that suddenly stopped working. The frontdoor endpoint has a single origin, which is an azure app service.
I can succesfully go directly to the app service, but when going to the frontdoor URL I get a 404.
This was working until ealier this week. As a test, I changed the origin to be another app service, and it can successfully hit that app service.  This shows I am getting to front door. When I change it back to the original app service, I continue to get the 404.
How can I troubleshoot this?
I don't see any logs at FrontDoor about the incoming request, but I might not know where to look.

Did you ever solve this Don?  I've run up against the same issue

Actually ignore.  This looks like it's a problem with the app service custom domain setup

You can troubleshoot this issue by going to the AzureDiagnostics logs for Front Door.   Under the "Logs" blade in Front Door:

Then you can query "AzureDiagnostics" in KQL and click "Run" to see the incoming requests.

You'll have access to many fields you can filter on in the requests, such as requestUri_s, httpStatusCode_s, etc.

That should be enough for you to get started troubleshooting the issue.
